# Why does an argument type of std::set accept {} as argumet but boost::container::flat_set does not?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.8, boost-container

I converted some methods from argument type `const std::set<>&` to `const boost::container::flat_set<>&` with the same template types being passed.
Now I have to change every occurrence of calls to these methods where the argument was `{}` and have to replace them with `typename()`.

Why is this, and is there some easier way?

boost_1_60_0 being used -- don't blame me!

To compile:

> g++ -std=c++11 test_set.cpp -D__FLAT__

or

> g++ -std=c++11 test_set.cpp

The error message is clear -- and I couldn't read the original.

I guess the `{}` can only be interpreted as an argument list, as the type is unknown.

```
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <boost/container/flat_set.hpp>
#include <boost/container/flat_map.hpp>

#ifndef __FLAT__
typedef std::map<int, int> MAP;
typedef std::set<MAP> SET;
#else
typedef boost::container::flat_map<int, int> MAP;
typedef boost::container::flat_set<MAP> SET;
#endif

static void show(const SET&)
{
}

int main(int, char**)
{   
    //SET s({});
    show({});
}
```

Comment: The type has an non-explicit initializer-list constructor, so `{}` as argument should be fine. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html. Please provide a proper [mre] including the error message it generates.

Comment: Compiler explorer doesn't support Boost 1.60, but with 1.64 it works fine: https://godbolt.org/z/YcqWbvnPK

Comment: @user17732522 which is strange, because the documentation for boost 1.64 still has it as explicit, changing in 1.66 to non-explicit

Comment: @Caleth Right, I forgot that the default constructor should be chosen for an empty `{}`, so the initializer-list constructor doesn't matter. It seems that older GCC versions accept the `explicit` default constructor in this case and that it wasn't clear how to handle this situation. I think this is related to https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1518.html.

Comment: Testing on compiler explorer, GCC 4.8 and earlier (in all minor revisions) accept the `explicit` default constructor, while GCC 4.9 and later (in all minor revisions) don't. So that makes me question whether the `g++-4.8` tag is really correct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, constructors for [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set) are non-explicit while [`boost::container::flat_set`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_set.html) are explicit.

Explicit constructors require you to *explicitly* indicate the type, and when you do `{}` you are not.

Also, in the commented line you are first constructing the object and then calling the copy constructor of `SET`. As the Boost's container has an explicit constructor, compiler is not able to deduce the type you need there so it cannot deduce that the `{}` was for creating a `SET`.

You can fix it in several ways:

```cpp
SET s{};
SET s{SET{}}; // ridiculous usage, just to illustrate the problem
show(SET{});
```